# OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `actors` model once compiled

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

This is my actor model.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ActorSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        minlength: [3, 'Actor Name must be at least 3 characters.'],
    },
    imdb_url:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('actors', ActorSchema);
```

This is my test file.

```
const request = require('supertest')
const Actor = require('../../models/actor')
let server;

describe('/actors', () => {
    beforeEach( () => { server = require('../../app');    });
    afterEach( () => { server.close() });
    describe('GET /', () =>{
        it("should return all actors", async () => {
            const res  = await request(server).get('/admin/actors');
            expect(1).toBe(1);
        })
    })
})
```

So, in a test file, I got this: `require('../../app');` which executes `app.js` code which has this line `require("./startup/routes")(app)` and in routes, I require models.

After I run npm test, it says :

> OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `actors` model once compiled.

How do I solve this?

I understand that require for actors model happen twice, but because of module caching, Actor model module has to be executed only once, but i guess it executes twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is being required twice therefore error is coming.

Remove this line from the test case.

> const Actor = require('../../models/actor');

Only app should call the model at once when you will start the server.

Suppose you have included model in app.js like

> this.actorModel = require('../../models/actor');

Access model like

> app.actorModel in your test case.

I think whenever your will require this code will run:

> mongoose.model('actors', ActorSchema);

Therefore no module caching will work.

Comment: 1) Why module caching doesn't work?  2) I need this model in test file so that I can make initial putting things in database

Comment: I made it work.  The error was typo (../../models/Actor'').  and not actor. by the way  do you know what this error is saying: 
This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: does request(server).get('/admin/actors') return promise?